# Word count application is not running on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop-streaming

This is my first time using hadoop for anything so I started working with basic program which is word count. On my local machine it works perfectly fine. Real issue is that I am unable to run in on hadoop clusters.

This is what I ran on terminal:

```
hadoop jar /home/hdoop/hadoop-3.3.4/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-3.3.4.jar \
-input /main/data.txt  \
-output /main/output \
-mapper /home/hdoop/mapper.py \
-reducer /home/hdoop/reducer.py
```

and this is where I am stuck:

[image]

I went to `http://localhost:8088/cluster/apps` but it is stuck at 0 for hours.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have zero "Active nodes" in YARN and zero "Total Resources"; therefore your app will be paused until the ResourceManagers report healthy NodeManagers.

Check the NodeManager process logs to see why it is not healthy.